# How do I get to categorical descriptor in a pandas categorical series?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical

I'm fairly familiar with pandas categorical dtype.   But, I'm having trouble accessing the nice ordered formatting of the categorical dtype at the bottom of a pandas series frame.

Note: I realize other questions have been asked that just gets the unique names.  But, this does not provide formatting of the ordering (Categories (3, object): ['low' < 'medium' < 'high']).

If series is y, I've tried:

> y.cat.categories #-> index (but without > ordering)
> y.cat.categories.to_numpy() --> array y.cat.ordered --> bool

```
y


Out[288]: 
    0      medium
    1         low
    2      medium
    3        high
    4      medium
            ...  
    437    medium
    438    medium
    439    medium
    440      high
    441       low
    Name: target, Length: 442, dtype: category
    Categories (3, object): ['low' < 'medium' < 'high']    # <<---- Trying to get this info 
                                                           # here programatically!
```

What I'm trying to get is the last line in the output above.

Answer (score 1):

Give df,

```
scoreDtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['low', 'medium', 'high'], ordered=True)
df = pd.DataFrame({'score':np.random.choice('low medium high'.split(' '), 50)})
```

You can get the categories using .cat the category accessor:

```
df['score'].cat.catories
```

Output:

```
Index(['low', 'medium', 'high'], dtype='object')
```

But, you can get the string representation of this object like this:

```
df['score'].to_string().rsplit('\n', 1)[-1]
```

Output:

```
"Categories (3, object): ['low' < 'medium' < 'high']"
```

Comment: Thank you.   I agree that answers the question.  I'm surprised I can't access this anyhwere as its in the pandas view.   (Categories (3, object): ['low' < 'medium' < 'high']).   I also tried df.cat.__repr__()

Comment: Surprised this doesn't do it:
y_q_c.cat.categories.__repr__()
Out[55]: "Index(['low', 'medium', 'high'], dtype='object')"

Comment: Yep, that string representation is part of the Series and not part of pd.Categorical nor pd.CategoricalDtype.  I couldn't find it anywhere else.